# How can I redirect output in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I work with program which usage is "program input-file output-file".
How can I write the result in STDOUT and don't write it into the output-file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `/dev/stdout` as the output filename.

Answer (score 2):

Use `/dev/fd/1` or `/dev/stdout` as the output file.  Some programs will recognize `-` to mean `stdout`, or will even use it automatically if the output file is omitted, but this is up to the individual program (unlike the `/dev` ones which are system services, although sometimes emulated by shells on systems that lack them).

Comment: Yes, with " - " option it is working nice. Thank you, geekosaur.